# Running different versions of Angular as webcomponents

Tags: angular, web-component

I'm trying to run different versions of Angular as webcomponents in a same page.

example:

```
<script src="module1.js" /> //has Angular 7 
<script src="module2.js" /> //has Angular 11 
<script src="module3.js" /> //has Angular 7
```

And in runtime each module overrides globalThis['ng']. So this mean that's Angular cannot support webcomponents with different versions, because Angular is settings some stuff as global. Maybe someone knows how to resolve this problem?

Comment: "`Maybe someone knows how to resolve this problem?`" - well, since you say "`this mean that's Angular cannot support webcomponents with different versions`", it would seem that your only choice would be to upgrade or downgrade, so that they all run the same version

Comment: But what about webcomponets, the concept said that we are can use any frameworks in the same application?

Comment: Frameworks built houses, Web Components are bricks. Do you really want to distribute N different versions of the (required) Framework core code to the client? Build Web Components with native code only and your Web Components are small, fast, and can be used anywhere without issues. If you add Frameworks or libraries to the mix you add trouble, upgrades won't be easy (remember Angular 1 to 2), you have dependencies.

Comment: make sense, thx for your answer

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer ... yet :-)  How about it, @Danny, want to post an answer? Maybe even add a little?

Comment: Its an opinion, not an answer